# How to change the range based on dropdown menu selection

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet where I am tracking baseball stats for my High School Baseball team. I have the script setup for every time a Hit Error or Run is recorded, I have a checkbox that is onEdit(e) to add +1 to the total stat.

```html
    //Away Run
function increment1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('X3').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('X3').getValue() + 1);
}
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'G10') 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('X3').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('X3').getValue() + 1);
}
```

I have a scoreboard section and a dropdown menu with all of the innings listed; I want to associate the checkbox with a specific range for the total runs and **also to each range associated to the current dropdown menu that is selected.**

[Image of the Google Sheet Scoreboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSg9L.jpg)

Just to break it down a bit more for clarity. Currently when "G10" is edited (Check box selected or deselected), "X3" has +1 to the current Value, additionally I want +1 to be added to a different range based on what is selected in the dropdown menu on "I2". So if "Top 1" is selected in the dropdown "P3" would have +1 to the value when "G10" is edited and so on based on the selected Inning

If "Bot 1" is selected then on edit of "G10" +1 to "P4" "Top 2" +1 to "Q3", "Top 3" +1 "R3", "Bot 3" +1 "R4" all the way to "Bot 7" +1 "V4"

[Link to a live copy version of the Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SkLBRYu_AivAyutr_xa1qj_PH2Qeg9zv_W0JB6RIYXI/edit?usp=sharing)

```
[What Happens] [3]

[What I want on one click][4]

[Change of dropdown menu what happens][5]

[Change of Dropdown what I want to happen][6]

[What I want to happen][7]
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand the logic of `Just to break it down a bit more for clarity.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your logic?

Comment: I have a check box in "G10" OnEdit which changes a value of "X3" by adding +1. I want the range to be associated with a dropdown menu which is in "I2"  Selecting a different item in the list changes the location of the range which will have +1 added to the current value OnEdit of the checkbox of "G10". So if the List of Items in the drop down menu changes to "Top 2" the range now is Q3 for the OnEdit of "G10", If the drop down changes to Bot 2 the range which the OnEdit of "G10" adds +1 to "Q4". , If the drop down changes to Top 3 the range which the OnEdit of "G10" adds +1 to "R3" , and so on

Comment: check box + dropdown menu selection = range x, checkbox + dropdown menu selection 2 = range y

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `check box + dropdown menu selection = range x, checkbox + dropdown menu selection 2 = range y`. And, when you change the dropdown list, you want to delete the checkbox of "G10" and put a number 1 to the cell "G10". Is my understanding correct? And your showing image is the sample input situation? if my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation as the image?

Comment: Every time the checkbox is true or false i want the selected range to increase by 1 value    https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbLXS.png What Happens 1
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvlKp.png Desired Outcome 1
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny9Iw.png What Happens 2
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxrvt.png Desired Outcome 2
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ckoq.png Desired Outcome 3

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the logic for your flow. For example, from https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny9Iw.png to https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxrvt.png , why are the cells of "CHS-1" and "HHS-1" from the empty to `1`? But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I have simplified everything all I want to do is click the check box and have a dropdown menu pointing to a range to add 1 digit to the range selected - Pics in order 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYzkd.jpg - 2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/P719D.jpg - 3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk66G.jpg - 4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwpBa.jpg - 5. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SohT.jpg - 6. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUXVU.jpg  - 7. https://i.stack.imgur.com/231S2.jpg - 8. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMWNI.jpg - 9. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb0Hf.jpg - 10. https://i.stack.imgur.com/teHt0.jpg

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful and I misunderstood your reply, I apologize again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following reply,

> I have simplified everything all I want to do is click the check box and have a dropdown menu pointing to a range to add 1 digit to the range selected - Pics in order
>
> 1. [image]
> 2. [image]
> 3. [image]
> 4. [image]
> 5. [image]
> 6. [image]
> 7. [image]
> 8. [image]
> 9. [image]
> 10. [image]

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the cell coordinates of the checkbox and dropdown list. So, in this sample, the checkbox and dropdown list are put to the cells "A1" and "B1", respectively.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const obj = {
    checkbox: "A1", // Please set the cell coordinate of checkbox.
    dropdownlist: "B1", // Please set the cell coordinate of dropdown list.
    values: { "K2": "K2", "K3": "K3", "L2": "L2", "L3": "L3" } // Please set the values and the cell coordinates in the dropdownlist.
  };
  const sheetName = "Sheet2";
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.getA1Notation() != obj.checkbox) return;
  const checkboxValue = sheet.getRange(obj.dropdownlist).getValue();
  if (!obj.values[checkboxValue]) return;
  const editCell = sheet.getRange(obj.values[checkboxValue]);
  const value = editCell.getValue();
  editCell.setValue(value ? value + 1 : 1);
}
```

- For example, if you want to add `1` to the cell "K5" under the value of "K2", please modify `values: { "K2": "K2", "K3": "K3", "L2": "L2", "L3": "L3" }` to `values: { "K2": "K5", "K3": "K3", "L2": "L2", "L3": "L3" }`.

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This got me to the point of what I needed to overcome, and I have a working script.

Comment: @Andrew Dunn Thank you for replying. I could correctly understand your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.